# username@host in ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am reading the [SSH Tunnel - Local and Remote Port Forwarding Explained With Examples](http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html)

With regarding to local forwarding, one can use

```
ssh -4 -L 9999:remote-host:8888 username@example.com -N
```

What I can not understand here is username@example.com. What example.com should be?

In my environment, I am running a server listening on port 8888 in host1, in host2 I run

```
 ssh -4 -L 9999:host1:8888 myname@host1
```

Accessing host2:9999, I will go to the login page. If I change myname@host1 to myname@host2, even myname@host3, I can also go to the login page.So I can not understand what should be specified after myname@

Comment: As @hek2mgl pointed out, you specify the username and the host of the server you are tunneling to in your case username@host1 if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I can not understand what should be specified after myname@

You need to specify a host

- where you can log in using ssh
- which can access port `8888` on `host1`

In your scenario it seems like `host1`, `host2` and `host3` fit this requirements. I would configure the firewall in a way that only one of these hosts can be accessed using `ssh` from your host. But it depends on what you are doing.

Comment: Seems I can understand now. the host specified after username is where the ssh server running, and this host has access to the outside world.